# Joining Threads from a loop : best practise

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a nested for loop which fires threads, looks something like this;

```
for SIZE
    for SIZE
        std::thread cellThread ([=]() { solver(i,j, field); return 1; });
WAIT FOR JOIN
```

Where i and j are int and field is a pointer to a float array (float*), I was wondering what the best practise would be to wait for thread convergence?

My idea was to have a global counter that waits for SIZE*SIZE and then continues the program. I've seen an array of threads being used and simply waiting for each thread to join (I would be using `std::thread* cellThread = (std::thread*)calloc(size, sizeof(std::thread));` as the constructor as my array size is dynamic.

Thanks.

Comment: why `calloc` appeared in C++ program?

Comment: If you want to do so you'll need to keep an array of threads (aka 'thread pool'), and join the threads outside the loop (otherwise the operations will be sequentially synchronized of course). Pseudo code also doesn't describe so well, what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Might be worth looking into std::async for this. Then you could store the results as futures and not worry about waiting for them. The results will be ready when you access them. If you are mainly doing this for performance I would recommend a thread pool with only as many threads as you have physical cores.

Comment: @UldisK Instead of insulting me you could offer an alternative.

Comment: @Bryan Chen I needed a dynamic array and, after running tests, I found that using calloc gave me not only faster allocation times than std::vector but also quicker access times.

Comment: `calloc` gives you raw memory, not an array of `thread`. The reason it's faster is probably because it doesn't actually construct any `thread` objects, or destroy them again, or handle exceptions, or any of the other things you probably forgot to do. Also if you didn't enable optimisations then any performance comparisons are useless.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The tests were done on blocks of floats and included allocation, both in release and debug builds. The code I am writing is for a simulation and so far I have not had a reason to write any exceptions as they have not occurred. I appreciate your informative responses.

Answer (score 4):

> My idea was to have a global counter that waits for SIZE*SIZE and then continues the program.

Why not just wait for each of the `thread` objects you have?

> I would be using `std::thread* cellThread = (std::thread*)calloc(size, sizeof(std::thread));`

I really hope not.

This should work:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.reserve(SIZE*SIZE);
for SIZE
    for SIZE
        threads.emplace_back( solver, i, j, field );
for (auto& t : threads)
    t.join();
```

Comment: +1 That pretty well resembles, what I wanted to express in my comment (pseudo code aside ;) ).

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely I think I phrased myself poorly but that is essentially what I planned to do when I mentioned the array of threads. Can I ask what your issue with my code for the array of threads is? Another user expressed disgust at it and I would like to know what crimes against programming I've committed. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Your use of `calloc` appalled me. That's not an array, it's a block of memory filled with zero bytes. You would need to use placement new and manual destructor invocations, and `free` the memory again, and handle exceptions manually, and keep track of the number of constructed `thread` objects. Or you can just use `std::vector` like anyone with any sense has used since the last millennium.